# How to open Access database with bat file and login to Microsoft Office 365 then run a macro

Tags: batch-file, macros

I need to open an access database, login, then run a macro usinf a bat file run from a scheduled task.

I have an access database that when its opened, it displays a login dialogue box with the Office 365 logo on it. the URL at the top left corner of the box has https:login.microsoftonline.com. The database is actually in a folder on the network. When I open it mannually I have to login to Office 365. I have opened the database using a scheduled task running a bat file with the following code but it stops with the login page being displayed. Is it possible to open the access db, login the office 365, and then run a macro?.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "\MyServer\databaseFolder\MyAccessDatabase.accdb" -x mymacro